# Dynamic canvas big map like google maps

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How to create big dynamic map in canvas (like google maps- with some kind dynamic tiles), when I scroll the map- the area should be loaded dynamically? I found this- https://github.com/slav123/SpryMap but this is rather for one big image not for dynamic loading

Comment: Stackoverflow deals mainly with coding related questions. So you might ask your question on Stackoverflow's new sister site that deals with software recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you check out [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/) ?

Answer (score 2):

I found something like this- very simple example, but it works pretty, found on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/42038/what-would-be-a-good-way-to-implement-render-a-2d-tiled-map-for-a-browser-game, first answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on google maps, i believe they have many small images that they dynamically load into the map, they are of different zoom levels and locations, but always the same size. Making it easy to know which to load. You would want to load a buffer around the edges of your canvas to help reduce a loading time if you scroll quickly.

You can see what i'm talking about if you open maps.google.com, it will load block by block and if you scroll you will notice that a buffer of a single tile is loaded around the viewing window.